# How can I update a Block Templates with dynamic data in WordPress Custom Blocks?

Tags: wordpress, react-hooks, wordpress-gutenberg

In the following code, I am trying to dynamically update a template with attribute data that is not available until the first useEffect call.  In the code below, the first render of course has emoty attributes and displays defaults.  I can trace the code and see the template get updated, but after the useInnerBlocksProps is called with the revised template, the data is still not rendered.  what am I missing?

```
export default function Edit(props) {
const { PanelBody, PanelRow } = wp.components;
const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;

useEffect(() => {

    setAttributes({'name': 'Edward Alan Thompson'});
    setAttributes({'birth_date': '1 jan 1900'});
    setAttributes({'death_date': '31 Dec 1990'});
    setAttributes({'imageUrl': 'http://wordpressdevel.local/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/1.png'});
}, []);

const blockProps = useBlockProps( {
    style:{minHeight: 40, width: '100%', border: "1px dotted red"}
});

const innerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps(
    {orientation: "horizontal"},
    {template: [
            [ 'core/columns', { columns: 2 }, [
                [ 'core/column', {width: "20%"}, [
                    [ 'core/image', { url: attributes.imageUrl??''} ]
                ] ],
                [ 'core/column', {}, [
                    [ 'core/heading', { content: attributes.name??''} ],
                    [ 'core/paragraph', { content: 'b. ' + attributes.birth_date??''} ],
                    [ 'core/paragraph', { content: 'd. ' + attributes.death_date??''} ]
                ] ],
            ]
            ]
        ]}
);

return (
    <div >
        <InspectorControls>
            <PanelBody title="General" initialOpen={true}>
                <PanelRow>
                </PanelRow>
            </PanelBody>
        </InspectorControls>
        <div {...blockProps}>
            <div {...innerBlocksProps}></div></div>
    </div>
);
```

}

I verified that the last render call does have the proper template definition, its just not what is displayed on the screen.

Comment: In `useEffect()`, do you retrieve dynamic values for 'name', 'birth_date', 'death_date', 'image_url' from an external API or interally via getEntityRecords() elsewhere in your code? Or are you simply trying to set a default value for those attributes?

Comment: I will be getting it in useEffect dynamically, but for now just doing proof of concept with static values.  And yes I know the std way is with backend render, but I don't want to do that

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, the issue seems to be with how `useInnerBlocksProps()` is called: the first parameter expects `blockProps` followed by the `innerBlocks` content, eg:

**edit.js**

```js
import { useEffect } from '@wordpress/element';
import { useInnerBlocksProps, useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
    // Nb. Removed code not related to issue for clarity

    useEffect(() => {
        // Call setAttributes once 
        setAttributes({
            name: "Edward Alan Thompson",
            birth_date: "1 jan 1900",
            death_date: "31 Dec 1990",
            image_url: "http://wordpressdevel.local/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/1.png",
        });
    }, []);

    const blockProps = useBlockProps({
        style: { minHeight: 40, width: '100%', border: "1px dotted red" }
    });

    const TEMPLATE = [
        ['core/columns', {}, [ // Number of columns not needed
            ['core/column', { width: '20%' }, [
                ['core/image', { url: attributes.image_url ?? '' }]],
            ],
            ['core/column', {}, [
                ['core/heading', { content: attributes.name ?? '' }],
                ['core/paragraph', { content: 'b. ' + attributes.birth_date ?? '' }],
                ['core/paragraph', { content: 'd. ' + attributes.death_date ?? '' }]
            ]]
        ]]]


    const { children, ...innerBlocksProps } = useInnerBlocksProps(blockProps,
        {
            orientation: "horizontal",
            template: TEMPLATE
        }
    );

    return (
        <div {...innerBlocksProps}>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Ref: [Inner Blocks: Using a react hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/#using-a-react-hook)

I came to this conclusion after testing your `template` definition by itself using `<InnerBlocks .../>` then checked what `useInnerBlocksProps()` expected.